I am trying to measure area% using FIJI particle analysis, but i cannot figure out how to build a macro
Hello Stackoverflow users,
I am currently working on my bachelors thesis, and i have over 1.000 images to analyze. For this reason, i would like to make a macro that can crop these images the same way, apply the same color threshold and measure area% above this threshold; and then adding them into one csv/excel/text file.Example of the Winogradsky column, containing the sulfur reducing bacteria i would like to analyze.I added an example image, and i would like to analyze what % of this image is black.
I have tried to manually crop the images, add the correct colour filter, then do a particle analysis. however every time i do this, i get absurdly low area%, trying to put this into a macro as shown below also does not work. I have added the macro i tried to make below, as you can probably see; i am quite new to image analysis.
//seting directory
input=getDirectory("Set directory here");
list = getFileList(input);
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        Wholecolor(input, list[i]);
function Wholecolor (input,filename){
    open (input + filename);

//open ROI manager
run("ROI Manager...");
roiManager("Show All");

// Assign raw opened image the name "currentImage"
currentImage=getImageID();

// cropping image
makeRectangle(834, 414, 3840, 3468);
run("Crop");

//Duplicate raw image to make a copy that will be modified to make a mask
run("Duplicate...", "title=Mask");

// Highlight the "Mask" image as the duplicate that will be thresholded to make the mask
selectWindow("Mask");
makeRectangle(1026, 492, 3504, 3294);
setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0);
run("Clear Outside");
run("Color Threshold...");

// Color Thresholder 2.14.0/1.54f
// Autogenerated macro, single images only!
min=newArray(3);
max=newArray(3);
filter=newArray(3);
a=getTitle();
run("HSB Stack");
run("Convert Stack to Images");
selectWindow("Hue");
rename("0");
selectWindow("Saturation");
rename("1");
selectWindow("Brightness");
rename("2");
min[0]=0;
max[0]=255;
filter[0]="pass";
min[1]=0;
max[1]=255;
filter[1]="pass";
min[2]=30;
max[2]=255;
filter[2]="pass";
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  selectWindow(""+i);
  setThreshold(min[i], max[i]);
  run("Convert to Mask");
  if (filter[i]=="stop")  run("Invert");
}
imageCalculator("AND create", "0","1");
imageCalculator("AND create", "Result of 0","2");
for (i=0;i<3;i++){
  selectWindow(""+i);
  close();
}
selectWindow("Result of 0");
close();
selectWindow("Result of Result of 0");
rename(a);
// Colour Thresholding-------------

run("Analyze Particles...", "display exclude clear summarize overlay");
    // Get particle analysis results and put them into a file 

//clear ROI manager and Mask image so there is a clean workspace for the next image in the folder
roiManager("Deselect");
roiManager("Delete");
close("Mask");
close(filename+"_HSB");

//save data collected by ROI manager to a .csv file titled "WInogradksy_results"

   dir=getDirectory("image");
   //Change the file name here
   name = "Winogradsky_results"; 
   index = lastIndexOf(name, "\\"); 
   if (index!=-1) name = substring(name, 0, index); 
   name = name + ".csv"; ///can change xls to csv, txt, etc.
   saveAs("Measurements", dir+name); 
   
close();
}
run("Clear Results");

I would appreciate any help with this problem, many thanks in advance!

I'd recommend posting this over at forum.image.sc The purpose of SO is more to clarify specific points in programming, not really to get advice on a bespoke analysis routine. Whereas the forum is the opposite. Anyway, I would advise running what you want to do, with the recorder on, if the result when you do it on one image is OK, then you can put that into your function and you should be good to go. It looks to me that your if() statement will never be triggered and I wonder whether the failed invert step explains the low %.


i would like to analyze what % of this image is black.

The first thing to do is: Define "black" (in your context).
Below please find what I get by applying the "Default"-threshold scheme to the "Hue"-channel of your sample image.
The corresponding %Area is about 27.22%.
The following ImageJ-macro code may get you started:
run("Set Measurements...","area area_fraction display redirect=None decimal=2");
run("HSB Stack");
setAutoThreshold("Default dark");
run("Measure");


Hello, this is a great start! Thanks so much!
